# 404 not found page does not work in NextJS app routing

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect to the 404 page if the page does not exist. I followed the instructions [here](https://maxschmitt.me/posts/nextjs-404-page-app-router) and my code is as follows in
`app/[slug]/page.tsx`

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { getPage } from "@/sanity/utils";
import { CustomPortableText } from "../components/CustomPortableText";

type Props = {
    params: { slug: string }
}

export default async function Page({ params }: Props) {

    const page = await getPage(params.slug);

    if (!page) {
        return notFound()
    }
    return (
        <article>
            <CustomPortableText paragraphClasses="my-6" value={page.body} />
        </article>
    )
}
```

The code works fine with existing pages. However, the groq returns `null` when a page does not exist and comes to the line `notFound` statement and shows Blank page with a console error
[image]

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

I don't use a custom 404 page. And have read the instructions on [the NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `react-redux` library or `ReactContext`, try removing the wrapper with `Providers` from the layout component... I had a similar issue, this helped!

Also I recommend create custom not-found page (according to docs):

`./app/not-found.tsx`

```js
export default async function NotFound() {
  return (
      <h1>404! Not Found</h1>
  );
}
```

You don't need `return` after call `notFound()`

Comment: I am using ChakraUI. Tried it without the wrapper and all your suggestions but no difference. BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think this was the answer. I've removed the other libraries and made it work. Thanks for your reply.